Flutter Build Error on Linux: Undefined References to GLIBC Symbols
I'm encountering an issue while trying to build a Flutter application for Linux. When running the command flutter run -v, I receive the following error during the build process:
[  +3290 ms] [1/21] Generating /home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-Phone-Application/linux/flutter/ephemeral/libflutter_linux_gtk.so, /home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-Phone-Application/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_basic_message_channel.h, /home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-Phone-Application/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_binary_codec.h, /home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-Phone-Application/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_binary_messenger.h, /home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-Phone-Application/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_dart_project.h, /home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-PhoneApplication/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_engine.h, /home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-Phone-Application/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_json_message_codec.h, /home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-Phone-Application/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_json_method_codec.h, /home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-Phone-Application/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_message_codec.h, /home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-Phone-Application/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_method_call.h, /home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-Phone-Application/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_method_channel.h, /home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-Phone-Application/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_method_codec.h, /home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-Phone-Application/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_method_response.h, /home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-Phone-Application/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_plugin_registrar.h, /home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-Phone-Application/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_plugin_registry.h, /home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-Phone-Application/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_standard_message_codec.h, /home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-Phone-Application/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_standard_method_codec.h, /home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-Phone-Application/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_string_codec.h, /home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-Phone-Application/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_value.h, /home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-Phone-Application/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_view.h, /home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-Phone-Application/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/flutter_linux.h, phony
[   +5 ms] [  +17 ms] executing: uname -m
[   +1 ms] [   +5 ms] Exit code 0 from: uname -m
[   +1 ms] [   +1 ms] x86_64
[        ] [  +40 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LegacyCanvasKitRemover' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FontSubsetArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'PubDependencies' is not required, skipping update.
[  +63 ms] Initializing file store
[        ] [  +33 ms] Done initializing file store
[        ] [ +118 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[        ] [  +12 ms] Skipping target: gen_dart_plugin_registrant
[ +632 ms] Skipping target: unpack_linux
[ +559 ms] Skipping target: kernel_snapshot_program
[   +3 ms] Skipping target: native_assets
[        ] Skipping target: kernel_snapshot_native_assets
[        ] Skipping target: kernel_snapshot
[ +955 ms] Skipping target: debug_bundle_linux-x64_assets
[   +3 ms] Persisting file store
[        ] [  +24 ms] Done persisting file store
[        ] [  +36 ms] build succeeded.
[        ] [  +11 ms] "flutter assemble" took 2,566ms.
[        ] [ +202 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 181ms
[        ] [        ] Running 1 shutdown hook
[        ] [        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] [   +8 ms] exiting with code 0
[ +115 ms] [2/7] Linking CXX shared library plugins/nb_utils/libnb_utils_plugin.so
[ +461 ms] [3/7] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/copper_sip_phone.dir/my_application.cc.o
[ +127 ms] [4/7] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/copper_sip_phone.dir/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.cc.o
[ +656 ms] [5/7] Linking CXX shared library plugins/flutter_webrtc/libflutter_webrtc_plugin.so
[ +189 ms] [6/7] Linking CXX executable intermediates_do_not_run/copper_sip_phone
[        ] FAILED: intermediates_do_not_run/copper_sip_phone
[   +5 ms] : && /snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/clang++  -g  -B/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -B/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -B/snap/flutter/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -B/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/ -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/snap/flutter/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/ -lblkid -lgcrypt -llzma -llz4 -lgpg-error -luuid -lpthread -ldl -lepoxy -lfontconfig CMakeFiles/copper_sip_phone.dir/main.cc.o CMakeFiles/copper_sip_phone.dir/my_application.cc.o CMakeFiles/copper_sip_phone.dir/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.cc.o  -o intermediates_do_not_run/copper_sip_phone -Wl,-rpath,/home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-Phone-Application/build/linux/x64/debug/plugins/flutter_webrtc:/home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-Phone-Application/build/linux/x64/debug/plug ins/nb_utils:/home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-Phone-Application/linux/flutter/ephemeral:  plugins/flutter_webrtc/libflutter_webrtc_plugin.so  plugins/nb_utils/libnb_utils_plugin.so /home/ruban/YAVAR/PROJECTS/Sip-Phone-Application/linux/flutter/ephemeral/libflutter_linux_gtk.so  /snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so /snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so  /snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so /snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so  /snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so /snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so  /snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo-gobject.so /snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so  /snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so /snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so  /snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so /snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so -lpthread -ldl -lm -lgcc_s -o intermediates_do_not_run/copper_sip_phone
[        ] FAILED: intermediates_do_not_run/copper_sip_phone
[  +56 ms] [   +2 ms] clang: error: undefined reference to 'bcmp@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
[        ] [   +1 ms] clang: error: undefined reference to 'mempcpy@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
[        ] [   +1 ms] clang: error: undefined reference to 'memrchr@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
[        ] [   +1 ms] clang: error: undefined reference to 'memmem@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
[        ] [   +1 ms] clang: error: undefined reference to 'memchr@@GLIBC_2.2.5'

Environment:

Flutter version: 3.24.0-channel stable

Operating System: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS


What I’ve tried:

Updating Flutter and dependencies: Ran flutter upgrade and flutter pub get.

Checking GLIBC version: Verified my glibc version with ldd --version.

Ensuring all required libraries are installed: Installed build-essential, clang, cmake, pkg-config, and libgtk-3-dev.

Cleaning and rebuilding: Executed flutter clean and flutter build linux.

Testing alternate installation methods: Currently using Snap but considering other installation methods.


Questions:

Has anyone encountered similar issues with undefined references to GLIBC symbols?

Are there specific versions of glibc or other libraries that need to be matched?

Could Snap's environment be causing these issues, and if so, how can they be resolved?


Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
